# Toggle marker color on click AND show popup

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a geojson featurelayer and for each marker I can bind a popup
 and I can modify the properties to change marker color onclick, but I can't mix both.
I want to change the color and show the popup. I followed this
[mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/change-marker-color-click/)

It seems that when I add a click event to change the color it "deactivate" the popup...
As soon as I remove this click event, the popup appears
EDIT: This code is working

```
featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
.loadURL( getUrl() )
.on('ready', setStyle)
.on('click', function(e) {
    e.layer.bindPopup(e.layer.feature.properties.name);
    resetColors();
    e.layer.feature.properties['old-color'] = e.layer.feature.properties['marker-color'];
    e.layer.feature.properties['marker-color'] = '#ffffb2';
    featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
    setPopup();
})
.addTo(map);
function resetColors() {
for (var i = 0; i < geoJson.features.length; i++) {
    geoJson.features[i].properties['marker-color'] = geoJson.features[i].properties['old-color'] || geoJson[i].features.properties['marker-color'];
}
}

function setStyle() { 

geoJson = featureLayer.getGeoJSON();
for (var i = 0; i < geoJson.features.length; i++) {

    if(geoJson.features[i].properties['d'] <= distanceLocal)
        var color = '#a1d99b';
    else
        var color = '#636363';

    geoJson.features[i].properties['marker-color'] = color;
    geoJson.features[i].properties['old-color'] = color;
}
featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
setPopup();
}
function setPopup() { 


featureLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    marker.bindPopup(marker.feature.properties.name);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using this line `featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);`

this way you change the context of feature layer every time, so in order to trigger both the popup and color alteration you need the following two steps

- change `e.layer.openPopup();` with `e.layer.bindPopup();`
- move this line before `resetColors();` i.e this line `e.layer.bindPopup();` would become the first line inside click function.

**Note:** If it doesn't work, don't hesitate to mention it in comments

Comment: Thanks for helping. I misunderstood the link between the geojson properties and the layer. I ended up with this